# Problem with directories in C

Tags: c, exec, fork, readdir, opendir

I'm making a program for Linux in C that recieves a directory as an argument, then for each file in that directory and each of it's sub-directories, calls a program called monfile. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DIR_ARG 1
#define DUR_ARG 2
#define SEC_ARG 3
#define LOG_ARG 4
#define OP1_ARG 5
#define OP2_ARG 6

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Teste aos argumentos
    if (argc < 5) {
        printf("Erro! Argumentos insuficientes!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Declaração de variáveis
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dentry;
    struct stat stat_entry;

    int fork_result;


    // Testa se o directório passado como argumento é válido
    if ((dir = opendir( argv[DIR_ARG])) == NULL)
    {
        perror(argv[DIR_ARG]);
        exit(2);
    }

    chdir(argv[DIR_ARG]);
    // Ciclo de propagação
    while ((dentry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {

        stat(dentry->d_name, &stat_entry);
        // Se for ficheiro regular
        if (S_ISREG(stat_entry.st_mode)) {
            fork_result = fork();
            if (fork_result == -1) {
                printf("file fork error!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (fork_result == 0) {
                execlp("monfile", "monfile", argv[SEC_ARG], dentry->d_name, filedes, (char *)NULL);
                printf("Erro no exec!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        // Se for directório vai criar um novo processo e passar dir para esse directório 
        if (S_ISDIR (stat_entry.st_mode)) {
            fork_result = fork();
            if (fork_result == -1) {
                printf ("dir fork error!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (fork_result == 0) {
                chdir(dentry->d_name);
                dir = opendir (dentry->d_name);
            }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Now, the result of this was...a ton of exec error messages and then a bunch of fork error messages, even though I was just calling this for a directory with a file and a sub-directory. This brought me 2 questions:
a) How was the cicle doing so many iterations?
b) What was wrong with the exec, seeing how monfile is built and in the same folder as mondir?

So, I decided to figure out what directory the program was looking at by adding

```
printf("%s\n", dentry->d_name);
```

at the beggining of the cicle, and it was somehow scanning every directory, even though it was called like this: mondir Subfolder1 ...(other args), being Subfolder1 in the same directory as mondir. What am I doing wrong here, both with the directory problem and the exec problem?

Comment: Any particular reason you're writing this program instead of using `find -exec`?

Comment: Lots of bugs here, one of which is `chdir(dentry->d_name);
                dir = opendir (dentry->d_name);` ... those are in the wrong order, or the latter should be `opendir(".")`.

Answer (score 1):

readdir will return "." and ".." so you code will walk up the directory tree, as well as repeating every directory forever - fork/exec bombing your machine.

Also, as mentioned, `find -exec` would seem a reasonable alternative?

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the "." ".." shennanigans. ABout find -exec, as I mentioned in the comments, it's a college project.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not handling sub-directories very well.  You stop processing the current directory (but leak a DIR pointer in the process since you do not do `closedir()` on the old one before overwriting with the new one) and then `chdir()` into the new directory.

You also don't avoid directory entries `.` and `..`; you probably do not want to process them, but `readdir()` will faithfully return them as the first two entries in each directory.  This accounts for the flood of processes.

You should look up the POSIX function [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) and use that - or not try handling directories until after your code is working.

Comment: Thanks, . and .. were indeed the problem, and thanks for reminding me about closedir!

Answer (score 0):

You're tripping over a very common mistake:  the names returned by `readdir()` don't have the source directory name prepended, so you have to put it there yourself.